# $rootScope:infdig error caused by filter?

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a filter on an array in an ng-repeat.

```
div.row(ng-repeat="log in logs | prepare_log | orderBy: 'log.created'")
```

In the prepare_log filter I'm doing this:

```
value.stack_trace = angular.fromJson(value.stack_trace)
```

If I change it to this:

```
value.stack_trace = angular.fromJson(value.stack_trace).reverse()
```

I get the infdig error.

I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm iterating over the stack_trace property in an inner ng-repeat.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are causing an infinite $digest loop because you are changing the model during the digest loop.

What happens behind the scenes is this:

- ng-repeat parses the collection expression to figure out what rows need to be 'stamped' out and instantiates a watcher to get notified when the collection changes
- every time the filter is run, you change one of the items by assigning a new value to `value.stack_trace`, triggering the watcher of the ng-repeat to pick this up and starting over and over again
- Angular detects the loop and aborts

To solve the problem avoid changing the model in your filter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Interesting! So what would you say is the angular way to preprocess my data after I fetch it?

Comment: You can fetch and manipulate (e.g. reverse) the data in your controller and then assign it to your scope. This will also be a lot better for performance because a filter in a template expression is evaluated every digest cycle. Feel free to post your code if you need help with the actual implementation.

Answer (score 4):

because angular will always trigger digest one more time to make sure there is no more changes. in every digest cycle prepare_log filter will be called and return a value. if return value is the same from last one, it means no more changes and the application state is stabilized, thus angular does not have to trigger an extra digest.

but in your filter, value.stack_trace will be reversed in every digest cycle, thus the application state is never stabilized, which causing infdig (infinite digest) error.

Answer (score 1):

Solving `infdig` errors caused by filters in an `ngRepeat` can be cumbersome and annoying. When you just want a quick fix, it is often enough to articulate **as long as the input array doesn't change in order or size, give me the same result**.

This is made a lot easier if the models you're dealing with all have a unique `id` property.

In that case, we like to deploy a generic filter stabilization approach:

```
angular
    .module( "app" )
    .factory( "stabilize", stabilizeFactory );

/**
 * Generalization of a filter stabilization approach.
 * As long as the input contains the same elements (identified by their `id`) and they are in the same order,
 * the same result array is returned, thus preventing infdig errors.
 */
function stabilizeFactory() {
    return function stabilize( filterFunc ) {
        return function stableFilter() {
            var array = arguments[ 0 ];

            if( !array || !array.length ) {
                return array;
            }

            var stabilizationId = idString( array );

            if( array.$$stable ) {
                if( array.$$stableId === stabilizationId ) {
                    return array.$$stable;
                }
            }

            array.$$stable   = filterFunc.apply( arguments );
            array.$$stableId = stabilizationId;

            return array.$$stable;
        };
    };

    function idString( array ) {
        return array.reduce( function appendKey( id, element ) {
            return id + element.id;
        }, "" );
    }
}
```

To use this, just wrap your own filter function in `stabilize()`, like so:

```
angular
    .module( "app" )
    .filter( "myFilter", myFilterProvider);

/** @ngInject */
function myFilterProvider( stabilize ) {
    return stabilize( myFilter);

    function myFilter( array ) {
        if( !array || !array.length ) {
            return array;
        }

        return array.filter( function( element ) {
                return element.something === "foo";
            }
        );
    }
}
```