# $rootScope:infdig error when paginating filtered data

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I'm using [ng-paginator-plz](https://github.com/kennethlynne/ng-paginator-plz) to paginate some data in my app. I also want to pass this data through some filters before displaying, so I'm doing:

```
<paginator class="paginator" data="filteredUsers = (users | filter:search)" page-size="20" export-paged-data-to="paginatedUsers"></paginator>
```

Then to display the data I `ng-repeat` through paginatedUsers. This works if I remove the filtering, but with the filter in place I get a `[$rootScope:infdig]` error.

Searching for this error lead me to answers like this: [$rootScope:infdig error caused by filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963462/rootscopeinfdig-error-caused-by-filter) - which suggest the issue is because the filter is being evaluated multiple times. How can I fix this?

**Edit**: I've added the following to my controller JS file:

```
$scope.filter = function(){
    $scope.filteredUsers = $filter('search')($scope.users);
};

$scope.$watch('search', function() {
    $scope.filter();
});
```

I also added `$filter` to the top where depdendencies are passed in. But this gives me a `$injector:unpr` error when the page first loads and whenever the filter is used. If I change the filter line to `$scope.filteredUsers = $scope.users;` the error goes (but obviously it doesn't do any filtering), so I guess there's something wrong with my code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter it manually in controller in the moments you think it's necessary to refilter data, and store filtered data in separate $scope variable.

With loDash for shortness.

```
$scope.filter = function(){
    $scope.filteredUsers = _.filter(users, function(user){return user.name.indexOf($scope.search) !== -1;});
    // or any kind of angular filters..
}
$scope.$watch('search',  _.debounce($scope.filter, 100));

<paginator data="filteredUsers" ....></paginator>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you've pointed me in the right direction, but I don't quite have this working yet. I've added some code to my question. I'm not sure if I should be using `_.filter()` or `_.debounce()` so that may be where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Did you change template? `data="filteredUsers = (users | filter:search)"` to `data="filteredUsers"`?

Comment: It would be more clear if you'd provided a fiddle, anyway. [Here is](http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/) a blank one.

Comment: Sorry yes, I had changed the template as well. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4756/ . Hopefully I've been able to distill this into a simple example. If you type into the search box you'll see the first list of users is filtered using your search. Below that you'll see how I'm trying to paginate the same filtered list. The error I get on this fiddle is slightly different - `Unknown provider: searchFilterProvider <- searchFilter` - I guess I'm referencing the filter incorrectly.

Comment: Yep. Angular slightly changes filter syntax time by time. For [1.2.1 version](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/guide/filter) used in fiddle it's `function(filterFilter) {filterFilter(this.array, 'a');}`. Also when you filter in template it's `| filter:search:'fieldName'`. (Here is)[http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4759/] your updated fiddle.

Comment: And yes, seems like paginator-plz doesn't work with template-filtered data, for some reason. Link to fiddle is broken. Here's [another one](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4759/).