# Infdig error when converting strings to objects in filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-infdig

I want to write a filter that converts array of strings to array of objects (it is simplification of my original problem). So, the `['a', 'b']` should become `[{id: 'a', label: 'A'}, {id: 'b', label: 'B'}]`.

However, my solution results in infinite digest cycle error.

```js
angular.module('MyTestApp', []).filter('propertiesWithLabels', function() {
  return function(properties) {
    var propertiesWithLabels = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
      propertiesWithLabels.push({
        id: properties[i],
        label: properties[i].toUpperCase()
      });
    }
    return propertiesWithLabels;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyTestApp">
  <div ng-init="myObject = {properties: ['a','b','c']}">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="property in myObject.properties | propertiesWithLabels">
        {{ property.id }}: {{ property.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not modify the model as in this question [$rootScope:infdig error caused by filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963462/rootscopeinfdig-error-caused-by-filter). Why does this error occur?

Comment: This happens because result of your filter is different each time. Correct answer is: your filter is bad, do not make filters like that. Just do such manipulation in controller.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov you are correct. what happening behind the scene is.. filter is creating new reference object every-time, on dirty check `oldVariable`!= `newVariable`(because reference has change) fires up new digest cycle..and this process doesn't get stopped still TTL of digest cycle reach..

Comment: Don't filters always create new values? I mean, filter `['a','b'] | filter:'a'` creates new array each time, doesn't it? `<span ng-init="array = ['a','b']">{{ (array | filter:'a') == (array | filter:'a') }}</span>` prints `false`.